# Deferring tasks in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a cloud function that triggers on a database  new object and needs to delete that object 8 hours later. Right now I'm using a setTimeout to schedule that operation, but I'm not comfortable with such method, as I know function execution should be fast (60 secs max I read somewhere).

Any idea on how to achieve this in a proper way?

Comment: There is nothing built in for deferring execution of your function. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/l6GMIt2rUHI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setTimeout()` method is definitely **not** the way to go, in this case. There is no guarantee that the Cloud Function instance will still be running 8 hours later.

Google doesn't provide a scheduler for Cloud Functions yet, and your best bet would be to create a schedule queue of some sort. When the object is created, add a task to the queue to delete it 8 hours later. Periodically (every minute, say) run a cron job via a cron service that triggers an HTTPS Cloud Function that reads the queue to see if there are any objects to be acted on.

Alternately, if the object has a create time associated with it, you could run an HTTPS Cloud Function periodically (triggered by an external cron job, again) that does a query for expired objects based on their create time and removes them.

Comment: I'm also using geofire to open a geoquery to send push notifications to users that enter a certain area. This geoquery has to remain opened for as long as the circumstances that trigger those notifications are met, so I'm cancelling it with another setTimeout. Is there any way to achieve this behavior by using cloud functions?

Comment: That's a slightly different question than this. Your best bet would be to open a new SO question to ask it.